# Why is console.log illegaly invocated as a function parameter?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

When I try

```
[1,2,3].forEach(alert);
```

it opens message box for every item of the array as expected.

But when I try

```
[1,2,3].forEach(console.log);
```

I receive following error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation
```

Why?

Comment: Is this issue specific to Google Chrome?

Comment: `[1,2,3].forEach(console.log)` works fine in Firefox.

Comment: @MathieuImbert I know that in IE `console.log` returns error itself unless debug console is on. I suspect it is not an ordinary function, but I'm not sure. Maybe each browser implement it different way?

Comment: For what it's worth, you can always do `console.log(1, 2, 3);` to see three separate elements. That may not fit your use case, though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Personally I get `Invalid calling object`.

See, `[1,2,3].forEach(console.log)` is essentially a shorthand way of iterating over the array and for each item running `console.log.call(theArray,theItem)`. However, `console.log` requires that `this` be an object of type `Console`, thus the error.

Try `[1,2,3].forEach(function(i) {console.log(i);})`

Comment: Excellent! I managed to solve it by passing the console into its context as you explained and it works: `[1,2,3].forEach(console.log.bind(console));` Could you please add it into your answer to help others running into this question?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, it doesn't work in Firefox, or at least not as you might expect:

```
[1,2,3].forEach(console.log)
```

Gives you:

```
1 0 [1, 2, 3]
2 1 [1, 2, 3]
3 2 [1, 2, 3]
```

Why? [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) has your answer:

> callback is invoked with three arguments:
>
> - the element value
> - the element index
> - the array being traversed

However,

```
[1,2,3].forEach(function(i) { console.log(i); });
```

Works exactly as you'd expect in both Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: I know - it is just odd to create anonymous function just to call native function. Thanks for useful explanation anyway.

Comment: @JanTuroň: Well the problem is the way JavaScript is dynamically typed, so you can call functions with any number of arguments (or none at all) of any type and it will *try* and do something. Sometimes it'll give you an error, sometimes it'll do something unexpected.