# Events with native vs. lambda functions

Tags: javascript, dom-events

Rather a technical question concerning JavaScript events:

Why does

```
window.onmousewheel = console.log;
```

throw an `Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation`, while

```
window.onmousewheel = function (e) {console.log(e); };
```

works just as expected and prints the event as string?
Why is the `console.log`, when assigned to `window.onmousewheel`, not just called with one parameter like the lambda expression?

Comment: [Chrome doesn't recognize console.log...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9612398/chrome-doesnt-recognize-console-log-when-its-called-log) ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8904782/uncaught-typeerror-illegal-invocation-in-javascript ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16615781/why-is-console-log-illegaly-invocated-as-a-function-parameter ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12944987/abbreviating-console-log-in-javascript ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5133649/alias-to-chrome-console-log ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5456709/create-shortcut-to-console-log-in-chrome

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5538972/console-log-apply-not-working-in-ie9

Comment: Try `window.onmousewheel = console.log.bind(console);`.

Comment: This is more of a question about why `foo.bar()` is different to `fn = foo.bar; fn()`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When function is called without explicit receiver, the receiver is `window` (or more generally the global object) or `undefined` depending on strictness. The function referenced by `console.log` requires that its `this` value is an instance of `Console`.

It is not usually done in user code but you could protect your methods from
generic calls as well:

```
MyClass.prototype.method = function() {
    if( !( this instanceof MyClass ) ) {
        throw new Error("Invalid invocation");
    }
};
```

Comment: thanks for the explanation, not some workaround!

Answer (score 3):

It all has to do with the scope of `console.log`

You *should* do:

```
window.onmousewheel = console.log.bind(console);
```

[image]